# Will the Acitvity screen not showing for long time if the service started from Oncreate Method?

Tags: android

I have an activity MainActivity.java. From OnCreate() method of main acitivity I have Started one service which connects to rabbit mq messaging server inside of the OnCreate() method of MyService.java(it extends Service). The issue is that the acvitiy screen take too long time to show because the rabbit mq connection establishment taking long time due to slow network..Then my app shows ANR message , how to overcome this and where to call startService to avoid anr message

Comment: you may want to use an `AsyncTask` for establishing the connection

Comment: You are probably on UI thread, so that's why you are getting ANR messages. Using service doesn't mean that is running on the background thread.

Comment: is it good practice if i start separate thread inside onCreate() method of service because i need to establish connection only once with rabbit mq server, and it is not good to create connection inside onStartcommand , it will invoke all the time if i call startService. i have never seen separate thread creation in service's oncreate() method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle your connection on a different thread. You have several options.

- Thread
- Runnable
- AsyncTask (preferred method by many programmers)

I would recommend AsyncTask, because there are tons of examples on this site and pretty much everywhere.

You need to do this regardless if you're using a Service or not. Remember that a service runs in the same thread as the User Interface. So maybe you don't even need the Service after all.

EDIT:
You can start the thread anywhere in your application, including in the Activity's `onCreate()`. If you choose to start the thread in the Service you can also start the thread anywhere including `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: is it good practice if i start separate thread inside onCreate() method of service because i need to establish connection only once with rabbit mq server and i hope it is not good to create connection inside onStartcommand too, it will invoke all the time if i call startService. i have never seen separate thread creation in service's oncreate() method. then where to create async task or thread.

Comment: thank you...Now i will start a new worker thread in onCreate() method of service and establish the connection as you said